# How to find the difference between two timestamp objects in Dart?

Tags: flutter, dart

So I am storing a Dart `DateTime` in firebase, which firebase stores as a `Timestamp` type.

When i read the data back into my flutter dart app, i am getting the result back in the format below.
Below is what i get back when i read it from firebase.

```
Start -> Timestamp(seconds=1604593808, nanoseconds=95000000)
End -> Timestamp(seconds=1604593816, nanoseconds=165000000)
```

I would like a way to get the difference between the timestamps. So the duration lapsed from the start time to the endtime. Would be perfect if someone knows how i can get the difference as a datetime object as well? How could i achieve this?

Comment: do End - Start. it should work or convert both into milliseconds and then subtract.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1st, you need to convert the result into `DateTime` format.

```
var data1 = Timestamp(seconds=1604593808, nanoseconds=95000000);
var data2 = Timestamp(seconds=1604593816, nanoseconds=165000000);

DateTime dateTime1 = DateTime.parse(data1.toDate().toString());
DateTime dateTime2 = DateTime.parse(data2.toDate().toString());
```

Then, you use the built-in `DateTime` method:

```
dateTime1.difference(dateTime2).inDays; // or in whatever format you want.
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the timestamp to `DateTime` using the [`toDate()`](https://github.com/FirebaseExtended/flutterfire/blob/master/packages/cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore_platform_interface/lib/src/timestamp.dart#L78) method and then compare the two dates using the [`difference`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/dart-core/DateTime/difference.html) method of the `DateTime` class, example:

```
var berlinWallFell = new DateTime.utc(1989, DateTime.november, 9);
var dDay = new DateTime.utc(1944, DateTime.june, 6);

Duration difference = berlinWallFell.difference(dDay);
assert(difference.inDays == 16592);
```

Answer (score -1):

I guess you can figure out how to get a time from your timestamp (haven't worked with this data type). Then all you need to do is

```
timeDiff = timeEnd.difference(timeStart).inMilliseconds;
```

Answer (score -1):

***Approach 1***

```
 final date1 = DateTime(1996, 08, 04);
 final date2 = DateTime.now();
 final difference = date2.difference(date1).inDays;
```

***Approach 2***

```
DateTime date1 = DateTime.parse('2019-9-11'); 
DateTime date2 = DateTime.now();
final result = date2.difference(date1).inDays;
print('$result');
```